# 404 error when trying to access a template with an beginning underscore _ after upgrading to 2.5.3

Tags: templates, ajax

I'm running into this strange issue I've never seen before. I have a template that starts with an underscore, I'm using it to pull in some results via ajax.

After upgrading to 2.5.3 and only on my local machine, I'm getting a 404 response when I try to access the template. Going to view the file in Template Manager, it seems like now every template that's starting with an underscore is grayed out.

Any idea what's going on here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you have `$conf['hidden_template_indicator'] = '_';` set? This could be causing the issue

Comment: Doh! That's it man, thanks. I just implemented EE Master Config and didn't know that setting was there. I'll accept the answer after the 8min time limit.